# How to solve: $\ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n^n + \frac {1}{n}}{(n + \frac {1}{n})^n} \ t^n $

Tags: limits, power-series, fractions

How can I solve:

$$\ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n^n + \frac {1}{n}}{(n + \frac {1}{n})^n} \ t^n $$

`t`is a whole number.

Thank you very much! Please tell me your ideas, even if you won't post the the result.

Comment: divide num. e denom. by $n^n$ and you will remain with $t^n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically just a guess, but I would expect the limit to be $\infty$. Since $n \to \infty$, $\frac 1 n \to 0$, so we can ignore that term, giving us:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{n^n} t^n=\lim_{n \to \infty} t^n=\infty$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand.

Comment: If the whole number is negative the last limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @Joanpemo Whole number usually means $0,1,2,3,...$. Obviously, if $t=0$, then the whole expression is always $0$, so I assumed $t > 0$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Thank you. I thought "whole number" usually means the same as "integer number", but some indeed define it as you say, so I guess "natural number or zero" would be more accurate.